# Selecting columns in SQL Server with different font size

Tags: sql-server

```
select col1, col2 from table_name
```

Here I need to set the font size of col1 as say 10 and col2 as 12.

Is that possible in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server is the database engine, it's not meant to display the results

Comment: No. The relational database doesn't send any properties with the result that control formatting (unlike SSAS).

Comment: It's impossible! You have to use reporting tools to be able to achieve that!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible directly through SQL Server.  SQL Server just works with data, it doesn't do a lot (and isn't MEANT to do a lot) with formatting for display.  However, as mentioned in the comments, there are SQL add-ons and tools that do offer that functionality.

Without those though, it would be the application that is requesting this information from the database that would have to:

- Make the request
- Receive the results (assuming no error)
- Loop through the result set, formatting (setting the size, font, color, etc...) 
        and outputting the returned values as needed